# angular: ng-class in ng-repeater , duplicate call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, duplicates, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

first of all sorry for my English.
my problem is:

i've this simple code:

```
<li ng:repeat="item in menu.items" ng:class="getMenuItemClass(item)"> 
<a ng:href="#{{item.url}}">{{item.label}}</a>
</li>
```

and this my getMenuItemClass:

```
scope.getMenuItemClass = function(item) {
   console.log(item)
   var hashPath = $location.hashPath || '/';
   if (hashPath === item.url) {
      return 'selected';
   }
   return '';
};
```

this is the example ready,
i don't know why, but in my real application it's triplicate! :0
can someone explain to me if i'm making a mistake?

http://jsfiddle.net/h7yKr/44/

I've update the jsfddle to the last version of angular, and now it's quadruplicate!
watch it
http://jsfiddle.net/h7yKr/46/

edit for clarication:
 the problem is that getMenuItemClass()
is called a lot more times more then required,
 try to open the jsfiddle and open the browser console and watch the console.log!

Comment: I don't see anything being tripled or quadruled - I just see two menu options, Home and Alt.  Can you clarify further?

Comment: ops sorry! you're right, the problem is that getMenuItemClass()
is called a lot more times more then required, try to open the jsfiddle and open the browser console and watch the console.log!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular can evaluate an expression multiple times during a `digest` cycle and hence execution of function happens again and again.

As explained in the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime) here

> Angular enters the $digest loop. The loop is made up of two smaller
>   loops which process $evalAsync queue and the $watch list. The $digest
>   loop keeps iterating until the model stabilizes, which means that the
>   $evalAsync queue is empty and the $watch list does not detect any
>   changes.

Since you $watch expression is a function it can get called multiple time.

Alternatively look at `$routeChangeStart` event in [$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route) service. 
You can subscribe to this event. 
Create a variable on your scope and do the `ng-class` binding to that variable